# Drawing a rectangle using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code so far. At first I made it draw circles which worked well. I thought that drawing rectangles would be as easy, but I have only been able to draw squares. I was hoping to have shapes of various widths and lengths. Do I know I need to change the box of (x1, y1, x2, y2) but how would I go about that.

```
def down(event): # A mouse event will be passed in with x and y attributes
global startx, starty # Use global variables for assignment
startx = event.x # Store the mouse down coordinates in the global variables
starty = event.y

def up(event):
    tk_color_string = color(red_intvar, green_intvar, blue_intvar)
    r = (startx-event.x)**2 + (starty-event.y)**2  # Pythagorean theorem
    r = int(r**.5)                                 # square root to get distance
    new_shape = canvas.create_rectangle(startx-r, starty-r, startx+r, starty+r,
                                     fill=tk_color_string, outline='#000000')
    shapes.append(new_shape) # aggregate the canvas' item
```

The whole code is over 100 lines long, so I hope this piece helps demonstrate what I am asking.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfWIA.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking.  Do you realize that to draw a rectangle all you have to do is add a little extra to either the x or y coordinate of one corner of the square?

Comment: I tried inserting an image, but it won't allow me too. I want to be able to draw them in varying shapes and sizes. no matter what I do they draw as squares. The code I am using wasn't just created by me I was just modifying it to use rectangles and not circles.

Comment: Is your question about rectangles or about images? Have you tried changing the coordinates for one corner of the square?

Answer (score 5):

I am providing an example code below that I just wrote on how to create rectangles in tkinter canvas with a mouse. I hope this helps you understand the relevant procedures and the methods you need. Thereafter, adapt it for your particular problem. Hopes this helps you and best regards.

**Example code:** How to create tkinter canvas that allows a user to draw rectangle objects with a mouse.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__( self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self._createVariables(parent)
        self._createCanvas()
        self._createCanvasBinding()

    def _createVariables(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.rectx0 = 0
        self.recty0 = 0
        self.rectx1 = 0
        self.recty1 = 0
        self.rectid = None

    def _createCanvas(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent, width = 800, height = 400,
                                bg = "white" )
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def _createCanvasBinding(self):
        self.canvas.bind( "<Button-1>", self.startRect )
        self.canvas.bind( "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopRect )
        self.canvas.bind( "<B1-Motion>", self.movingRect )

    def startRect(self, event):
        #Translate mouse screen x0,y0 coordinates to canvas coordinates
        self.rectx0 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.recty0 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y) 
        #Create rectangle
        self.rectid = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx0, self.recty0, fill="#4eccde")
        print('Rectangle {0} started at {1} {2} {3} {4} '.
              format(self.rectid, self.rectx0, self.recty0, self.rectx0,
                     self.recty0))

    def movingRect(self, event):
        #Translate mouse screen x1,y1 coordinates to canvas coordinates
        self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        #Modify rectangle x1, y1 coordinates
        self.canvas.coords(self.rectid, self.rectx0, self.recty0,
                      self.rectx1, self.recty1)
        print('Rectangle x1, y1 = ', self.rectx1, self.recty1)

    def stopRect(self, event):
        #Translate mouse screen x1,y1 coordinates to canvas coordinates
        self.rectx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.recty1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        #Modify rectangle x1, y1 coordinates
        self.canvas.coords(self.rectid, self.rectx0, self.recty0,
                      self.rectx1, self.recty1)
        print('Rectangle ended')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry( "600x400" )
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Overview of Steps and Methods Used:**

1. Create a canvas widget in `Tk()` window using `tk.Canvas()` method
2. Bind mouse events `<Button-1>`, `<ButtonRelease-1>` and `<B1-Motion>` with their callbacks to `tk.Canvas` widget.
3. For each of these events:
   3.1 Convert mouse pointer screen x, y coordinates to canvas coordinates using methods `.canvasx(event.x)` and `.canvasy(event.y)` and store these converted corrdinates in variables `self.rectx0`, `self.recty0`, `self.rectx1`, `self.recty1`. `event.x` and `event.y` provides the mouse pointer screen coordinates. 
   3.2 Use canvas method `.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, option, ...)` to create rectangle or use canvas method `.coords(tagOrId, x0, y0, x1, y1)` to modify rectangle coordinates. Here, `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, `y1` denotes the rectangle object's top left corner and bottom right corner x & y canvas coordinates, and `tagOrId` denoted the rectangle object ID. 
   3.3 Only for `<Button-1>`, need to store the created rectangle object's ID in a variable. This variable provides the value to tagOrId whenever `.coords() method` is called during `<B1-Motion>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>`.

Comment: Is there a way to force the user to create squares instead of rectangles, like only letting the user move cursor in the direction of the diagonal?

Comment: @sadesoda Sure. You need to amend the method `movingRect()` to impose a square algorithm. The amount of change in x must the same as the change in y.  Finally,`self.rectx1` and `self.rectx1` must give you a square. If you really need help, post your question as a new question as this section is meant for commenting of an answer.